# How to hide/show elements at certain breakpoints with Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show/hide elements on certain break points, like what I would do with Bootstraph or Zurb Foundation.

I see in the documentation here https://material-ui.com/system/display/#api we add

`display={{ xs: 'block', md: 'none' }}`

to our elements. I have done this, but I don't get any results - no hiding/showing elements, no errors, no compilation problems.

Would anyone know how this is done?

My code is:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles)
const PhoneActionLink = ({ children, prefix, href, value, display, isFirst, ...other }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
      <Button
        display={{ xs: 'block', md: 'none' }}
        {...other}
      >
        {children}
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles'
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles)
const PhoneActionLink = ({ children, prefix, href, value, display, isFirst, ...other }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Box component="Button" display={{ xs: 'block', md: 'none' }} m={1}>
      {children}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Wrap the `Button` component within `Box` component.

Answer (score 8):

**The answer strictly depends on the version of MUI you're using.**

The accepted answer should work for MUI v4 and prior versions, but didn't work for me (MUI v5).

I dug into the documentation [From the official MUI website](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#hidden) and found that the following code works for me:

```
<Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', md:'none' } }}>
   {children}
</Box>
```

I'm guessing that the sx attribute allows you to modify some of the CSS properties based off specific breakpoints.

I'm no expert so I can't fully explain the solution, but I'm hoping that this solution helps another person out there.

Comment: Yes, this is correct for MUI 5. `sx` does not exist in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other solutions, you could also use the  component. Although it's deprecated now.